# Why HA Canvas is unable to redraw 300 lines every frame?

Tags: android, canvas, hardware-acceleration

*Foreword: please note that I am only a beginng Android dev so it is entirely possible I am missing something obvious or are doing very silly things.*

### Why am I doing this?

I am developing an app that needs live scrolling line graphs. New values arrive approx. every 100ms and I would like to animate their arrival by scrolling the graph to the left over 100ms/16ms ~ 6 animation frames. I need to display around 50 values from three different sources on two graphs for a total of 300 lines to be drawn. The entire graph is re-drawn every display frame (16ms).

[image]

### Why am I doing it this way?

**I do realise that there are more efficient ways of doing the above.** Instead of re-drawing everything every frame I could store the previously drawn bitmap and only add a little slice to the right. I could also do it the hardcore way in GLES.

But I figured we have hardware acceleration for a reason and 300 straight lines does not exatly sound like the most complex problem in the world. After all, if hardware acceleration can do dynamic lighting at 60 FPS surely it can draw a couple lines for me at realtime speed?

### The problem

Well, it turns out even a hardware accelerated canvas has a hard time drawing this many lines efficiently. It does (barely) keep up when graphs are on their own:

[image]

...but things get progressively worse with layout complexity — more and more frames get "descheduled for several milliseconds, contributing to jank" (as systrace puts it):

[image]

### Implementation details

I think I am doing all the basic things right: drawing is done in a custom view's `onDraw` (since `SurfaceView` and `TextureView` do not offer a hardware accelerated canvas), line coordinates are calculated on a background thread so that `onDraw` does not do any extra work, points are also generated on a background thread, I go the extra mile to invalidate only the right part of the screen.

You can find all the gory details and an APK to try out in [my GitHub repo](https://github.com/davidcie/GraphTest). The two files of interest are [GraphView.java](https://github.com/davidcie/GraphTest/blob/master/app/src/main/java/net/davidcie/graphtest/GraphView.java) and [MainActivity.java](https://github.com/davidcie/GraphTest/blob/master/app/src/main/java/net/davidcie/graphtest/MainActivity.java); not posting them here due to length. Layout is very simple:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="net.davidcie.graphtest.MainActivity">

    <net.davidcie.graphtest.GraphView
        android:id="@+id/graph1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:focusable="false"/>

    <net.davidcie.graphtest.GraphView
        android:id="@+id/graph2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:focusable="false"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

In the repo you will also find [systraces](https://github.com/davidcie/GraphTest/tree/master/traces) for both the simple layout in the repo and a more complex layout in the actual app that the test case was extracted from.

### Help!

Bearing in mind the foreword disclaimler I would love to hear from more experienced of you:

- What is the root cause of long frame rendering times?
- Whether even with hardware acceleration the Android graphics subsystem is not fast enough to draw lines real-time and I am using the wrong tool for the job?
- If perhaps there is a way to extract graphs from the view layout / DisplayList so that we save on layout traversal?
- If I can do anything else to help Android draw, eg. set some magic property that *you* know speeds things up (like "not a touchable surface")?

Comment: You need to post your view's code.  Without that we're making guesses at best.

Comment: As I wrote I would rather not post the main view and the graph view due to size; both are linked above (GraphView.java and MainActivity.java).

Comment: Hmm, anyone? Is there really no other way but caching the bitmap?